# Does macOS Monterey automatically install apps to folders?

Tags: install, mac-appstore, launchpad

When installing a Sudoku app from the App Store, I went to check the install progress in Launchpad only to find it was automatically installing the app in a folder *I* had created in Launchpad called Games. Is this a default thing in Monterey? Do apps install to folders with the name of a category they're in?

Comment: Is this a real folder visible in Finder, or just a grouping Launchpad does?

Comment: Grouping in Launchpad

Comment: It affects Steam Games too

Comment: So it's not actually Finder creating folders, it's Launchpad grouping applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out, this is a feature in macOS Monterey.

When you install an application from the App Store, if it is labeled or categorized as a game, it will actually install in a specific folder called Games. This also puts the Chess.app in the folder as well but for some reason leaves it in the "Other" folder at the same time.